Python Coding: Why are some implementations are Functions and some are Methods
For example, when using the "print" Function it works like this:
print (string)
However, when using the "lower" Method it works like this:
string.lower()
Why isn't lower a normal function that works like this:
lower (string)
Is there a reason to implement it as a method?
(From my recent reading, a method is really just a function inside of a class.)
Does this have something to do with python strings being immutable so the string has to be "recreated" using a method instead of a function?
I tried lower(string) and it says "NameError: name 'lower' is not defined"
which makes sense since it's a method.

Because print() is something you can do with anything, but lower() is specific to strings. What would the lowercase of an integer mean?

What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?

There are cases where there's a sound principle (like print(), as Barmar shows above), and then there are cases where the decision was made back in Python's very early development history and would be made differently in more modern times; to answer comprehensively we'd need to evaluate each function case-by-case. Since not every case can be derived by reasoning about principles, the practical answer is to learn the language and library as it actually exists.

(That's not just true of Python; it's true of pretty much everything, including real-world languages; everything old is full of exceptions that exist for historical reasons).

That NameError doesn't make sense because lower is a method, it makes sense because there is no such name defined in that scope. If you did lower = str.lower, then lower('FOO') would work

People tend to get attracted towards python for its simplicity. It's not just you! Many including me would have been happier if we get the option of using all the function and methods with the same syntax. But we should think about the convenience of the people who create the language as well.
Though these functions would have been created in C-language, For the sake of understanding, I'm writing in python.
Let us assume you want to create several methods to handle strings. The easiest way to design is using OOPS i.e using class and methods. For instance,
class strings:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def upper():
        txt =  self.text
        for x in txt:
            if ord(x) in range(97, 123):
                idx = txt.find(x)
                x = chr(ord(x)-32)
                txt = txt[:idx] + x + txt[idx+1:]
        return txt

    def lower():
        # some code here

    def capitalize():
        # Some code here

In this way, all the string related codes could have been encapsuled into a single class.(Of course would be written in C, Not in python)
While calling also..
strings('Hello').capitalise()
strings('Hello').upper()
strings('Hello').lower()

Then where has the class name strings gone? Please remember: for the sake of understanding, I took the example from python. Similar kinds of things are available in c and other languages as well. There are methods to omit the class name and considering the parameters as string. What My answer indicates is: 'The reason for this is convenient in grouping and debugging and  to explain about the simplicity in grouping and selecting the optimal algorithm'
